# Discord.py Word count and User ID in a uwu.json

Tags: python, json, discord.py

Hello i am just starting out with python and i wanted to create an discord UwU word counter.

My Goal is to store the data in an uwu.json like:

```
{ 852419718819348510 : uwu = "1"awo = "12",
 another id : uwu = "2" }
```

I have looked on github but i couldn't find anything related to that..
I tried to use it like its wirtten here: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.10/Lib/json/__init__.py

Sadly i couldn't get it to work.
Answers are appreciated

Comment: That's not valid JSON syntax.

Comment: yes i dont know how to do it?

{
    "888088625072439368": [
        "852419718819348510: uwu = "1",
        "888379542681575484: uwu = "2"
    ]
}

thats my guess

Comment: also lukas ... that wasnt my question

Comment: Yes, it's not your question, but how are we supposed to help you if the syntax is incorrect? Also you're not showing any effort of solving the problem by yourself, StackOverflow is not a "code it for me" type of site, you're supposed to ask *specific* programming questions. Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
import json
my_data = {
 "uwu": 5
}
with open("uwu.json", "w") as f:
json.dump(my_data, f)
```

loading the data is very similar `json.load()`